# Can I mark some piece of text as bold?

Tags: formatting

For example, lets say I have a line like:

> Hello, this should be bold.

Then is there any way to change one or more words to be bold, so it will appear on the screen as:

> Hello, this should be **bold**.

For example, in some text editors I can select a word and press a "bold" button, and the text remains bold for the lifetime of the file.

I'm using gVim 8.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Have a look at the [Txtfmt plugin](https://github.com/bpstahlman/txtfmt)

Comment: Are you dealing with text files like txt, markdown or with source code? For source code, it is non-sense to bold some code.

Comment: It is a text file

Answer (score 3):

Well, it is not that simple.

What you can come up with -- use syntax definitions. But this bold text you will create would be temporary, it will not be saved with your file like word processing software does.

So to the code.

```
func! RegionMakeBold()
  hi MyBold gui=bold
  let l_start = getpos("'<")[1]
  let l_end = getpos("'>")[1]
  let c_start = getpos("'<")[2]
  let c_end = getpos("'>")[2]+1
  execute 'syntax region MyBold start=/\%'.l_start.'l\%'.c_start.'c/ end=/\%'.l_end.'l\%'.c_end.'c/'
endfunc

vnoremap <leader>b :<C-U>call RegionMakeBold()<CR>
```

Having this in your `.vimrc` will allow you to make bold text out of visually selected blocks. Just select text, press `<leader>b` and text should be bolded.

[image]

It will probably not work for the files with defined filetypes/syntax.

Comment: Problem with matching on absolute coordinates is that when you start modifying the file, the contents will shift... But given the question is quite open ended, perhaps this is a good answer?

Comment: Actually, @filbranden this is one of the cases where there is no reason (or way) to answer. The question is unclear and unanswerable until it’s been clarified, so *here* (unlike the mapping Q) Id rather not see answers. But thats just me

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Totally agree with your point! Looking forward to the next moderator elections on Vi and Vim.SE! 

Comment: @filbranden got to get out of beta first 

Comment: The new (and experimental) text properties feature should be a better fit for this (and fix @filbranden's remark), but you'll need at least 8.1.1341 (May this year).

Answer (score 2):

Plain text files do not have formatting options like a word processor does. If you want that WYSIWYG functionality like a traditional word processor, then I recommend a word processor like LibreOffice.

However, there are document formats that support common formatting with additional syntax. Markdown is a lightweight syntax that is still readable as a textfile but vim syntax highlighting can somewhat show you what the final result will look like, e.g. with pandoc's markdown https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc-syntax

[image]
From pandoc's README.

Another option is using LaTeX which has lots of precise control for formatting. For small documents, compiling is very fast so you can quickly get a preview of your document.

Comment: You dont need pandoc to have markdown syntax highlighting.

Comment: The plugin integrating vim with the pandoc document converter has such a function. ":help [vim-pandoc](https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc/blob/master/doc/pandoc.txt)" explains that `<localleader>b     toggles bold [vn]`. The help page contains a list of other mappings.